# Find directory inside subdirectory using macOS terminal

Tags: find, directory, macos

I want to find a directory `x` inside a particular subdirectory `y` using the macOS terminal, but I do not know the directories preceding `y`.

This command - `find / -type d -name "x"` works for finding `x`, but there are many directories named `x` across the system so I need to find the `x` which is under the directory `y`.

I tried -

- `find / -type d -name "/y/x"` or
- `find / -type d -name "y/x"` or
- `find / -type d -name "../y/x"`

but these do not show me the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `-path` primary:

```
find / -path '*y/x'
```

> ```
> -path pattern
>          True if the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters (``['', ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of
>          pattern.  These characters may be matched explicitly by escaping them with a backslash (``\'').  Slashes (``/'') are treated as normal characters and do
>          not have to be matched explicitly.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From a `zsh` shell:

```
print -rC1 -- /**/y/x(/D)
```

The `**` glob matches down into subdirectories, and the `(/D)` glob qualifier specifies that the resulting pathnames must be directories and that the pattern should match hidden names too (as with `dotglob` in `bash`).

Or the approximate equivalent from `bash` release 4 or later (i.e., installed from Homebrew on macOS, not the default `bash`):

```
shopt -s globstar failglob dotglob
printf '%s\n' /**/y/x/
```

The `globstar` shell option in `bash` enables the use of the `**` globbing pattern, while `failglob` makes pattern matching fail with an error if there aro no matches.  The `failglob` behaviour is the default in `zsh`, as is the availability of `**`.

`find` would probably be faster though:

```
find / -type d -path '*/y/x'
```

This would find any directory called `x` living in a directory called `y` somewhere under `/`.

Or, you may have a functional `locate` utility with which you may do

```
locate '*/y/x'
```

This would be the fastest alternative, but would only return results accessible by any user on the system, and may not be entirely up to date.